# Determine a vector for a $3\times 3$ matrix so it becomes positive orthogonal

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

> Two orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are given:
>
> $v_1=(-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})$ and $v_2=(0,1,0)$
>
> Let $Q$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix with the first, second and third column be $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ respectively.
>
> Determine $v_3$ so $Q$ becomes a positive orthogonal matrix.

I'm stuck. Any hints? I know that $det(Q)=1$ for it to be positive orthogonal, but I'm not sure how to get there from the given information.

Comment: What, besides $\det(Q)=1$, does $Q$ being an orthogonal matrix imply?  In particular about the columns of $Q$?

Comment: $v_3$ has to be orthogonal with the other two vectors or just one of them? @Bye_World

Comment: $v_i^T v_3 = \delta_{i,3}$ ... there are only two options for $v_3$. One yields a positive determinant, the other one a negativ one.

Comment: It has to be orthogonal to both $v_1$ **and** $v_2$ **and** it needs to be normalized (just like $v_1$ and $v_2$ already are).

Comment: @Bye_World

I'm honestly still not sure how to proceed. I'm expected to do this by hand, but I don't see how (yet). The only examples I've seen done by my professor are when we already a matrix to work from, not when two columns in the positive orthogonal matrix are given.

Comment: Let $v_3 = (a,b,c)$.  Then you want to solve the system of equations $$\begin{align}(-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})\cdot(a,b,c) &= 0 &\text{($v_1$ orthogonal to $v_3$)} \\ (0,1,0)\cdot(a,b,c) &= 0 &\text{($v_2$ orthogonal to $v_3$)} \\ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}&=1 &\text{($v_3$ normalized)}\end{align}$$
There will be two vectors which solve all of these.  Choose the one that makes the determinant positive.

Comment: The two vectors I found were $v_{3a}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, \sqrt{1-1\sqrt{2}})$ and  $v_{3b}=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, \sqrt{1+1\sqrt{2}})$, but neither of them make $det(Q)=1$, inserted as a column vector in $Q$. @Bye_World

Comment: @Steve Those aren't the solutions that [WolframAlpha gets](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-sqrt(2)*a%2F2+%2B+sqrt(2)*c%2F2+%3D+0,+b+%3D+0,+sqrt(a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2)%3D1).

Comment: Hmm, weird. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: There is a direct solution: take $v_3 := v_1 \times v_2$ (cross product).

Comment: Cheers @JeanMarie. That will save me some time if a similar problem appears in my exam.

Comment: Obviously $(1,0,1)$ is orthogonal to the given vectors.  Hence you have only two candidates, namely $\pm(\sqrt{2}/2,0,\sqrt{2}/2)$.  By quick inspection you'll choose the vector with negative coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The vector cross product of any two vectors is orthogonal to each.